# Please, can someone solve this equation

Tags: equation-solving

Solve the equation: e^(at)+e^(a(t-T)) = 2.
Please can someone help me to solve this equation. I need a in terms of t, T.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please add to your question the code you have tried.

Comment: Because this is a transcendental equation, `Solve` cannot handle it.  `FindRoot` can obtain numerical solutions, of course.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a comment above, `Solve` cannot handle this transcendental equation.  Nonetheless, by inspection one solution of the `Exp[a t] + Exp[a (t - T)] == 2` is `a = 0`.  This and the more general solution can be obtained graphically.

```
ContourPlot3D[Exp[a t] + Exp[a (t - T)] == 2, {t, -5, 5}, {T, -5, 5}, {a, -5, 5}, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, T, a}, PlotPoints -> 25]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reduce can solve it. Clearly there are many solutions.

```
 In[1]:= Reduce[Exp[a t] + Exp[a (t - T)] == 2, {a, t, T}]

    Out[1]= (C[1] \[Element] Integers && -2 + E^(a t) != 0 && a != 0 && 
       T == (a t - 2 I \[Pi] C[1] - Log[2 - E^(a t)])/a) || a == 0
```

FindInstance can also give many solutions:

```
In[6]:= FindInstance[Exp[a t] + Exp[a (t - T)] == 2, {a, t, T}, 2]

Out[6]= {{a -> 40 - (299 I)/10, t -> 127/5 - (27 I)/10, 
  T -> (99/1247005 - (1099 I)/
      2494010) ((15993 + 
        54760 I) + (18080 + 9040 I) \[Pi] + (20 - 40 I) Log[
        2 - E^(93527/100 - (43373 I)/50)])}, {a -> 0, 
  t -> 67/10 - (67 I)/10, T -> 11/5 - (43 I)/5}}
```